# LU Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-decomposition

I'm having trouble understanding which answer is correct.

I'm currently reading a paper: [lecture 12](https://www.math.ohiou.edu/courses/math3600/lecture12.pdf) - They give the following example:

Let:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3 \\ 
2&5&12 \\ 
0&2&10 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then they say state that L and U are given as:

$$
L =\begin{pmatrix}
 1&0&0 \\ 
 2&1&0 \\ 
 0&-2&1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
U = \begin{pmatrix}
 1&-2&3 \\ 
 20&-1&6 \\ 
 0&0&2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Using an online calculator [bluebit](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/calculate.aspx) they give:

$$
L =\begin{pmatrix}
 1&0&0 \\ 
 0&1&0 \\ 
 0.5&-0.250&1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
U = \begin{pmatrix}
 2&5&12 \\ 
 0&2&10 \\ 
 0&0&-0.500 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which one is therefore right in this instance? I need to calculate the determinant of a large matrix and therefore trying to implement the LU Decomposition and are using these two as a guide and want to know if it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct when the typos are fixed:
$$
\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}}^L
\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 3 \\ 0 & -1 & 6 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}}^U
=
\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 3 \\ 2 & -5 & 12 \\ 0 & 2 & -10 \\ \end{bmatrix}}^A$$
as in the lecture notes.

I believe there's going to be a combination of bugs with the software approach; likely involving typos, but also the LU decomposition also involves a permutation matrix.  It instead gives:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0.5 & 0.25 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -5 & 12 \\ 0 & 2 & -10 \\ 0 & 0 & -0.5 \\ \end{bmatrix}=A$$
which is probably not the decomposition you want.

Comment: So the software is calculating using the permutation matrix as well? No, since, I need to calculate the determinant. My matrix is going to be quite big. I'll look at the software approach and see which answer I arrive at :)